# IPNs getting sent a URL that is no longer available

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn, paypal-subscriptions

I run a subscription based website, which was going great until the developer of the subscription component I used ceased development.

Due to my lack of knowledge of programing a solution to set up something to catch the exisiting IPNs and convert them into something my new subscription component could manage, I simply manually added new subscriptions into the new subscription component, and kept a manual log of when subscriptions had been cancelled from Paypal's end, then altered the entries accordingly.

This was fine as the defunt subscription component still recieved the IPNs and sent back the correct notification to Paypal, and I kept an eye on things.

Now we have upgraded our security and moved to a new server, and the old subscription component has been marked as being vunerable, so moving it over also to keep this system I have going is no longer viable, and I am getting warnings from Paypal about IPNs not being recieved properly.

What should I do about this?

I can't turn of IPNs because my new subscription component uses them (perfectly).

Is this something a developer could look at and fix for me? I simply want the subscription IPNs from the old system to be recieved somehow (I am totally happy keeping things running manually on my side for older subscriptions).

Is there a way to turn off IPN notifications for just the subscriptions that are trying to send to a paricular URL?

Is there an easier sollution?

Any help would be muchly appreciated, I am worried that my IPNs will get turned off all together which would end up being a lot more work for me!

Kind Thanks,

Thomas

Comment: I use this service: https://ipnforwarder.com/ so then I can change the notify url when ever i want (and also can send the ipn to multiple urls)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot modify the IPN notification URL that are sent to your old subscriptions.
If you want to stop receiving notifications on your old subscriptions you need to cancel the old subscriptions and create a new/similar one.